# rotate character in local Y axis

Tags: opengl, directx, graphic

In 3D scenes, every frame, we keep updating the local world 4x4 matrix which can transfer the 3D object from local coordinate to the world coordinate system.
But I can't figure out the matrix which can makes the 3D object  rotate itself along itself local Y axis. Because I don't know the 3D object's local up vector, I only know the local->world matrix and keep updating it. How does people deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the object, you need a rotation matrix. That should be clear. And most libraries have methods for generating such rotation matrices.

Your problem seems to be what to do with that matrix. You want to use it to modify the existing world transform. There are basically two options. In the following, I assume a column-major matrix layout as is used by OpenGL. Matrix orders for DirectX are reversed.

Option 1: Multiply on the left:

```
newWorld = rotationMatrix * oldWorld
```

This rotates the object in the *global* coordinate system.

Option 2: Multiply on the right:

```
newWorld = oldWorld * rotationMatrix
```

This rotates the object in its *local* coordinate system. This is probably what you're looking for.

Btw, if you have the world transform, you know the local y-axis, which is just the second column of the matrix.